# Search for a specific picture in google drive folder - Search file name by title

Tags: image, file, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drive

I have a list of possible image file names in a spreadsheet.  I'm trying to get the file (if exist) and insert it into the cell next to the name. But I get an error when I call `.hasNext()`. The code that I am using is:

```
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var i = 0;
      var numberOfRows = sheet.getLastRow();

      for (i=0;i<numberOfRows;i+=1) {
        var range = sheet.getRange(i+1,1);
        var data = range.getValue();
        var file =  DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID_HERE").searchFiles(data);
        if (file.hasNext()) {
          var rangeDest =sheet.getRange(i+1,2);
          var output = file.next();
          rangeDest.setValue("=image(\"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + output.getId() +"\")");
        };
      };
};
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get exactly? That might help others understand the question better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from this line:

```
var file =  DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID_HERE").searchFiles(data);
```

Should be:

```
var searchString = 'title contains "' + data + '"';

var file =  DriveApp
  .getFolderById("FOLDER_ID_HERE")
  .searchFiles(searchString);
```